# How i can use entity_metadata_wrapper for new database entry and update data in Drupal 7

Tags: hooks, entities, 7

How i can use entity_metadata_wrapper for database entry and update data in Drupal 7

I am using below code to save entry in database but not finding logic to update existing entry

```
    $node = new stdClass();
    $node->type = "event";
    $node->uid = $user_id;          
    $entity_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',$node);
    $entity_wrapper->title->set($row->title);
    $entity_wrapper->body->set($row->description);
    $entity_wrapper->status->set(0); 
    $entity_wrapper->promote->set(0);
    $entity_wrapper->comment->set(0);
    $entity_wrapper->field_eventbrite->set($row->eid);          
    $entity_wrapper->field_venue->set($row->name);
    $entity_wrapper->field_eventbrite_city->set($row->city);
    $entity_wrapper->field_privacy->set($row->privacy);
    $entity_wrapper->field_repeats->set($row->repeats);
    $entity_wrapper->field_date_period->set(array(
        'value' => str_replace(' ', 'T',$row->start_date),
        'value2' => str_replace(' ', 'T', $row->end_date),
    ));
    $entity_wrapper->field_eventbrite_url->set(array(
        'url' => $row->url,
    ));
    $entity_wrapper->save();
```

Please help. Please let me know if require more information is needed.Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple

```
// $nid - nid of node you want to udate
$node = node_load($nid);
$entity_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',$node);
...
$entity_wrapper->field_eventbrite->set($row->eid);          
$entity_wrapper->field_venue->set($row->name);
$entity_wrapper->save();
```